# Ubuntu Launcher Customization

Tags: ubuntu, launcher, ubuntu-unity

Is there some way to futher customize the Ubuntu Launcher?

I would like to make a few tweaks like moving it to the right instead of left and making it "pop" in and out instead of the scrolling it does by default.

I have looked at [unity-launcher-customizing](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/unity-launcher-intro.html#launcher-customizing) but it does not cover those possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently as far as Ubuntu 11.10 goes there are very limited options in-terms of customization to the unity launcher .

There are a few un-official options available .

Check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher) on askUbuntu , and this [post on webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/install-ubuntu-unity-bottom-launcher.html) , which outline ways to customize the launcher to some extent

Comment: That is a shame.  As an operatin system, I really like Linux in general and Ubuntu in particular, but I would like it much better with a few tweaks to that Launcher and they seem like they should be relatively simple things.  I find I trigger it fairly often accidentally.

Comment: Don't worry if you don't like the current Interface you can always fallback to xfce(Xubuntu), which is also really good and quite customizable. Anyway All the customization you asked features should come up in Ubuntu 12.04 next April.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman: More customization will most likely be available in Ubuntu 12.04, with all the... er... bug testing going on.

Comment: I['ll take a look at some of the third party options.  Any idea when 12.04 will be out?

Comment: I think you can get the time from the number 12.04 itself , 12 for 2012 and 04 for April . So Ubuntu 12.04 will be out sometime in the end of April 2012

Comment: Heh, I've been using Linux off and on for years, but I'm new to Ubuntu and didn't notice the connection.  Thanks.